# MS Access SQL - Find numbers with decimals no end to Zero (,00)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am having a table and i would like to find all numbers where it doesn't end to ,00 but with decimal number like ,01 or ,23 or etc...

```
My Table Data              Desire Output

id     s                  id     s      c
 1   32,00                 1   32,00   NULL
 2   13,13                 2   13,13  13,13
 3   55,05                 3   55,05  55,05
 4   76,00                 4   76,00   NULL
```

I would like to create a sql query to create column c like

`iif(s IS ZERO AFTER DECIMAL, NULL, s)`

Is it possible in MS ACCESS SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For positive numbers, you can use `floor` or `int()`:

```
iif(s <> int(s), . . .
```

Comment: `int` is working, `floor` i am getting error. It is all positive numbers.

Comment: @YvetteLee How are you using it and what does the error say?

Comment: ` iif(Price <> floor(Price), Price,"")` and `Undefined function <name> in expression. (Error 3085)`. Is it possible to keep 2 numbers after decimal. Now, with `int` it is making `,10` to `,1`

Comment: @YvetteLee . . . I'm not sure I understand your question, but perhaps you want `round()`.  You can always ask a *new* question with appropriate sample data and desired results.